# � (question mark) getting displayed in place of inverted comma while getting text from mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql, text

Everytime i get some text to display on a page using php echo, all the inverted comma's are replaced by some stupid question mark signs like this: �

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Encoding: 
Page- charset=utf-8
Database- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: What character encoding is your page/database?

Comment: well that's kinda french to me :P Lemme see where i can find the encoding and will get back to you. Must be in the head tag somewhere

Comment: the page is charset=utf-8

Comment: And the mysql homepage shows : MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: Could you try and post the inverted comma here?  I would like to see if I can copy it, find out what number it has.

Comment: well if i try to write it's .. it looks like this it�s .. i am not sure whether u are able to see that weird question mark in between (If that's what you're trying to ask)

Comment: Well I changed the encoding on my page to the encoding of the database and that worked! But just out of curiosity i would like to know that would it make any difference if i put a code between the text i am storing in a php variable and displaying it?


For eg:

 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text t     <div id="something"><img src="something"/></div>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

would it still display the image properly?

Also i am using nl2br() for that variable

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just matched both the encoding of my page and database. They were different. Made them the same and that worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Authough the collation of the database is "utf8-unicode-ci", the connection built by PHP side might use latin1 charset. So you would better check that by

```
echo $mysqli->character_set_name();
```

or

```
echo mysqli_character_set_name ($conn);
```

To set the charset to utf8, do

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8′", $conn);
```

or

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Hope it helps.